# How to display a list of widgets inside a ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have a list(*showContainerList*) of widgets and I want to display the contents in a **ListView.builder** but I don't actually know the way around it

Below is my code

```
List<TodoContainer> showContainerList = [];
  addContainer() {
    showContainerList.add(
        TodoContainer(
      cardTitle: taskName.text,
    ));
  }
```

I tried code below but does not seem to work

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: showContainerList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: const TodoContainer(),
                );
              })
```

Comment: Can you add your code fro the entire page?

Comment: it's not allowing me to post the edit because of too many code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: showContainerList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: showContainerList[index],
                );
              })
```

Comment: **Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.**  That is the error it raises after using your code

Answer (score 0):

The below code is what worked for me

```
Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: counter,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  return TodoContainer(
                    cardTitle: taskName.text.toString(),
                  );
                }),
          )
```